# solve a exponetial inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

Given a exponential inequality:
$$
e^x - x \leq a, x\geq 1,
$$
where $a>1$ is a constant. I want to know how much $x$ should less than， like
$
x\leq ?
$

Comment: i think we can use expansion of the $e^x$ for the comparision

Comment: sorry，i don't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
e^x-x &\leq a, \qquad a > 1, \qquad x \geq 1 \\
\Rightarrow \qquad e^x &\leq x + a \\
\Rightarrow \qquad -e^x &\geq -(x+a) \\
\Rightarrow \qquad -e^xe^{-(x+a)} &\geq -(x+a)e^{-(x+a)} \\
\Rightarrow \qquad -e^{-a} &\geq -(x+a)e^{-(x+a)}
\end{align}
$$

Now let's consider the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
For real numbers $y$ and $z$ the equation
$$ye^y=z
$$
holds if and only if $w=W_{k}(z)$ for some integer $k$ and $z \geq -e^{-1}$.
Here $z=-e^{-a}$, and
$$
a>1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad 0 > -e^{-a}\geq -e^{-1}.
$$
[image: Lambert W branches]

Here's the Lambert W function graph from the wiki page. The upper branch (blue) with y ≥ −1 is the graph of the function $W_0$ (principal branch), the lower branch (magenta) with y ≤ −1 is the graph of the function $W_{−1}$.
Therefore, we have
$$
-W_{-1}(-e^{-a})-a \geq x \geq -W_0(-e^{-a})-a.
$$
Since $x\geq 1$ and $-W_{-1}(-e^{-a})>1$
$$
-W_{-1}(-e^{-a})-a \geq x \geq 1
$$
Note there's no solution if $-W_{-1}(-e^{-a})-a<1.$

Answer (score 3):

First of all, $e^x-x$ is an increasing function.

The equality occurs at
$$e^{x_*}-x_*=a \implies x_*=-W\left(-e^{-a}\right)-a$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. So

$$e^{x}-x\leq a \implies x \leq x_*$$